# `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` graceful handling of non-existing dir

Tags: c++, std-filesystem

I have the following code:

```cpp
for (const auto& x : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir)) {
    // do stuff with x
}
```

`dir` might not exist, and I want to treat this case as if the dir is empty. I can't seem to come up with a nice option.

- If I guard everything with `try`/`catch`, then I'll be catching the iteration code exceptions as well, I don't want that.
- If I move `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` construction up and guard it with `try`/`catch`, it becomes verbose, and I'll have to re-throw all other exceptions (won't it screw up stack traces and such?).
- If I use the non-throwing constructor of `directory_iterator`, I'll have to throw `std::error_code` for other errors. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Why not simply check [`std::filesystem::exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) or [`std::filesystem::is_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_directory)?

Comment: @JeJo it might be more elegant code-wise, but it allows for races. That's unlikely to happen, but I wish my language to make it easy to do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

There are `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` [overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/directory_iterator) that accept a `std::error_code` parameter. They will yield an instance that compares equal to the end iterator if an error occurs rather than throwing.

```
std::error_code ec;
for (const auto& x : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir, ec)) {
    // do stuff with x
}
```

won't throw if the directory doesn't exist or if the path is a file. (My understanding is that if the iterator has at least one match then `operator*` on the iterator could throw due to catastrophic filesystem corruption or similar though.)

Answer (score 2):

According to `std::filesystem::directory_iterator`'s documentation it has both default and move constructors. So:

```cpp
std::filesystem::directory_iterator iter;

try {
    iter=std::filesystem::directory_iterator{dir};
} catch(...)
{
    // catch it
}

for (const auto& x : iter) {
    // do stuff with x
}
```